# Question about Record Pointer as a Function Variable

Tags: pointers, delphi, record

If I define the following procedure:

```
procedure get_String(var aStringPtr: PAnsiChar);
  function set_ReturnValue(aInputValue: AnsiString) : PAnsiChar; overload;
  var
    iLen: Integer;
  begin
    iLen   := Length(aInputValue);
    Result := AnsiStrAlloc(iStringLen + 1);
    System.AnsiStrings.StrPLCopy(Result, aInputValue, iLen);
  end;

var
  iData: AnsiString;
begin
  iData := 'Hello World';
  aStringPtr:= set_ReturnValue(iData);
end;
```

I am able to call the 'get_String()' procedure and get a string back by executing the following code:

```
var
  iMyStr: PAnsiChar;
begin
  get_String(iMyStr);
```

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to create a 'get_Record()' procedure that returns a properly filled record pointer:

```
  TMyDataRec = record
    ProductID: Integer;
    DownloadURL: WideString;
    MaintenanceDate: AnsiString;
  end;

type
  TMyDataRecPtr = ^TMyDataRec;

procedure get_Record(var aRecordPtr: TMyDataRecPtr);
var
  iData: TMyDataRec;
begin
  iData.ProductID       := 1;
  iData.DownloadURL     := 'www.thisisatest.com';
  iData.MaintenanceDate := '02/29/2023';

  aRecordPtr := <...>
end;
```

How do I populate 'aRecordPtr' so that a call to the 'get_Record()' procedure returns the proper data?

So far, all my attempts result in an access violation.

Comment: Why are you returning a pointer to the record rather than returning the record by value?

Comment: @David Heffernan I am using a pointer because the function is defined in a DLL. But it is called from a Desktop application.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. Doesn't matter what type of module it is. If you the issue is interop the pass the record as a var or out param. And avoid the poor solution in the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically records and record pointers are declared together, as follows:

```
type
  PMyDataRec = ^TMyDataRec;
  TMyDataRec = record
    ProductID: Integer;
    DownloadURL: WideString;
    MaintenanceDate: AnsiString;
  end;

// Note that the `PMyDataRec` pointer can be defined before the 
// `TMyDataRec` record, if done in the same 'type' block.
```

You get the access violation because you rely on stack memory, which doesn't exist anymore when the procedure exits.
You need to allocate memory for the record with the `New()` method.

```
procedure get_Record(var aRecordPtr: PMyDataRec);
var
//  iData: TMyDataRec;
  iData: PMyDataRec;
begin
  new(iData); // this is missing
  iData.ProductID       := 1;
  iData.DownloadURL     := 'www.thisisatest.com';
  iData.MaintenanceDate := '02/29/2023';

  aRecordPtr := iData; //<...>
end;
```

Note also, you don't need the `iData` record pointer, you can operate directly on the `aRecordPtr` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful and accurate answer.

Comment: Don't forget to pass the `PMyDataRec` pointer to `Dispose()` when you are done using the record

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I will. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it a procedure in the first place, if you want to return a record pointer? Just allocate the memory and return the pointer as the function result:

```
function get_Record: PMyDataRec;
begin
  New(Result);
  Result^.ProductID       := 1;
  Result^.DownloadURL     := 'www.thisisatest.com';
  Result^.MaintenanceDate := '02/29/2023';
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
var
  Data: PMyDataRec;
begin
  Data := get_Record;
  try
    // data now points to a TMyDataRec allocated on the heap
    WriteLn(Data^.DownloadURL);
  finally
    // Don't forget to free the memory when you no longer need it
    Dispose(Data);
  end;
end;
```

You can leave out the ^ most of the time as the compiler automatically assumes it where it is safe to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
Why make it a procedure in the first place? Valid point. I guess, I was so focused on trying to solve the problem that I missed the point.